Pytorch massive loss when learning from basic data
I have a very basic machine learning application I'm trying to make, basically I want the model to try and predict each month of the next year based on the dummy data I've provided but I'm getting huge loss Loss: 5206342.5000 and the predicated values are so off from what I would expect Predicted values for each month of next year: [-0.043424129486083984, 0.041442010551691055, -0.16847632825374603, -0.18227830529212952, 0.4619046151638031, 1.128817081451416, 0.05658513307571411, 0.1113058477640152, 0.2900705337524414, 0.21394489705562592, 0.2618725001811981, 0.3829265236854553] I'm very new to machine learning, why am I seeing such massive loss and such wrong values predicted?
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Example historical data (replace with your actual data loading)
data = {
    'ProjectId': ['666d60f2604698f1383d94e4', '666d60e2604698f1383d9495', '666d5fb1604698f1383d8e8f'],
    'Year': ['2023/2024', '2023/2024', '2023/2024'],
    'July': [0, 0, 0],
    'August': [0, 0, 0],
    'September': [0, 0, 0],
    'October': [0, 0, 0],
    'November': [0, 0, 0],
    'December': [10000, 5000, 100000],
    'January': [0, 0, 120000],
    'February': [0, 0, 0],
    'March': [0, 0, 0],
    'April': [0, 0, 0],
    'May': [0, 0, 0],
    'June': [0, 0, 0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Example: Extract X (input features) and y (target values)
X = df.drop(['ProjectId', 'Year'], axis=1).values.astype(np.float32)  # Convert to float32
y = df.drop(['ProjectId', 'Year'], axis=1).values.astype(np.float32)  # Assuming y includes next year's forecast

# Example: Splitting into training and validation sets
# Assume last row for validation, rest for training
X_train = torch.tensor(X[:-1], dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(0)  # Add batch dimension (1 sample)
y_train = torch.tensor(y[:-1], dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(0)  # Add batch dimension (1 sample)
X_val = torch.tensor(X[-1:], dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(0)  # Example single project for validation

# Define LSTM model for forecasting
class LSTMForecast(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(LSTMForecast, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        lstm_out, _ = self.lstm(x)
        out = self.fc(lstm_out[:, -1, :])  # Predict based on the last LSTM output
        return out

# Initialize the model, loss function, and optimizer
input_size = X_train.shape[-1]
hidden_size = 64
output_size = y_train.shape[-1]

model = LSTMForecast(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Training loop
num_epochs = 100
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = model(X_train)
    loss = criterion(outputs, y_train)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if (epoch+1) % 10 == 0:
        print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}')

# Example: Making predictions for next year's forecast
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    forecast = model(X_val)
    forecast_values = forecast.numpy().tolist()[0]  # Convert to numpy and list

print(f'Predicted values for each month of next year: {forecast_values}')


The issue is due to the magnitude of the values you are trying to predict. The model on initialization will predict values around mean 0, var 1. Since this is very far away from the values you want to predict, the loss is high.
You should preprocess your values to have a more reasonable scale. Since your output values cover multiple orders of magnitude in range, you should try a log transform.
